# Issue with nginx reverse proxy and ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am getting this error with nginx reverse proxy in docker containers:

SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream

I'm a little baffled with this as i've never seen this error before and i use the exact same process on other servers/websites without any issue. I've checked the config numerous times and i'm a bit lost.

My proxy container nginx config:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_verify_client off;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://website-container:443;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the relevant part of the nginx config of the actual website container:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        index index.php index.html;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 
        ssl_verify_client off;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
             rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
        }

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass balfp-php:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

        }

        # deny access to apache .htaccess
         location ~ /\.ht {
             deny all;
         }

         error_log /usr/share/nginx/logs/error.log;
         access_log /usr/share/nginx/logs/access.log;


    }
```

The ssl certificates are bind mounted into the proxy container and they appear in the container in the correct location:

```
volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/usr/local/etc/ssl/certs
```

As i say i use this configuration on a number of servers and they all work fine, so i'm not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the listen:

listen 443;

Changed to

listen 443 ssl;